# Ruby on Rails Paperclip open in new window

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using PaperClip with this code:

```
link_to "OPEN", @worequest.attach.url
```

Is there a way to open the file in a new browser tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To send a file:

You can use the send_data or [send_file](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file) method in your controller action:

> The 'disposition' option specifies whether the file will be shown inline or downloaded. Valid values are ‘inline’ and ‘attachment’ (default).

so this line in a controller's action will open the image in the browser (and not download it):

```
def get_image
  send_file '/path/to.jpeg', :type => 'image/jpeg', :disposition => 'inline'
end
```

### To open a link in a new tab:

You can also provide a `:target => '_blank'` to the Link_to (will open the link in a new tab)

```
link_to "New tab", url, :target => '_blank'
```